# Micro SD cards - fastest possible?

Tags: pi-4, pi-zero-w, memory

I'm using a Pi Zero W with a micro SD HC and a Pi4 with a XC-I card.
My questions:
whats the fastest micro SD card the Pi Zero and Pi 4 will support?
I'm aware that the Pi Zero can read XC but will it be at full speed?
Would the Pi4 / zero support full speed for a XC-II card?

Comment: If you look around at benchmarks online, it seems to max out at 40-50 MB/s, and higher rated cards are not necessarily better.  With a Sandisk Ultra (UHS-I/class 10, rated at 80 MB/s) I get ~50 MB/s for an idealized write (`dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=4M count=256`).

Comment: The speed ratings of SD Cards are related to burst writing i.e. Video. This has nothing to do with the way the Pi works (random R/W), but anything beyond SD10 will make no difference

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/sd-card-speed-test/ may be of interest